# How to implement instance segmentation on Android?

Tags: android, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite, semantic-segmentation

Is there any instance segmentation model (library) that works on Android devices?
[DeepLab](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab) unfortunately does "just" semantic segmentation, [YOLACT](https://github.com/dbolya/yolact) required CUDA. [Mask R-CNN](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN) could work, but I couldn't find any implementation or example.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to train it on your own dataset or just use Mask R-CNN into android?

Comment: Actually I'm interested in both.

Comment: From the github code I see that Mask R-CNN is 3 years old. You have to try training it with latest tensorflow version to have compatibility with conversion to tflite. But noone will guarantee the conversion if there is no operators compatibility. I see in some forums that a lot of people have given up trying... I recommend to find latest papers inside paperswithcode.com for instance segmentation...search for Tensorflow implementations and try to train and get the saved model to convert...Check first operators compatibility